# Base64 - Save as base64 in DB and display to frontend without creating file but BLOB or?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

NOTE : I use Reactjs in Fronted and Nodejs/express in Back

First I have an file input and I know how to display image using the  `FileReader()` API.

Now I have image data in Base64 like this : `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/sABFEdWNreQABAAQAAABQAA...`

**Is it safe or best practice to save it directly to DB (MongoDB) ?**

**How to create url of this image after fetching it from DB (without creating image file in Nodes) just using the Base64 data?**

**My  End goal is to get url like this : `www.example.com/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkq/` without creating file in backend**

Example :

```
// base64 from DB :
const data = data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkq;
// Then method here
// Note this scenario should done in frontend
const makeUrl (data) => {...}
// Then the image now have full url like
// makeUrl(data) => result  will
 www.example.com/image-from-base64.jpg // or
 www.example.com/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkq/
```

Answer (score 0):

Base64 is never a good idea to store an image in a database as it takes 30% more space. Consider using a Binary String. Also avoid storing images in database and consider alternatives like Amazon S3.

To use the Base64 image as just set the href of the link to be the Base64 data

```
<a href = "Base64data">example.com/image</a>
```

If using Javascript use -

```
document.getElementById('link-id').href = 'base-64 data';
```